# NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription prompt doesn't pop up

Tags: ios, core-location

When I ran the app the NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription prompt came up once but never came up again after running it multiple times.

The app is still zooming into the current location and the Apple location.

The app works, but the question does not pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization, the question is asked only once, whether you tap "Allow" or "Deny". But you are still able to see the description in the Settings app, in Privacy settings, then Location services, and then your specific app. A description text should be displayed at the bottom of the view.